Is there a central place in Mobile Connect to edit the JOIN keyword logic much like the STOP keyword?
Here's my scenario. Whenever a subscriber texts STOP to my short code, I have a Code Snippet embedded into the STOP message to update a Salesforce flag from TRUE to FALSE.
However, for JOIN, I don't see a similar way to do this because I'm actually opting subscribers in via a Journey using the Send SMS activity. So consequently, I see all these messages attached to the JOIN keyword:

Do I have to go to each and every message listed here and include my AMPScript Code Snippet one by one?

You can only have one active opt-in template per keyword, that's the only place you would have to change it
